# Ajax PHP script is not working - contact box with php ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hey guys I'm trying to make a contact form where people can contact me.

What I want want is something that people could fill, and if they click "Send", they get a message like "Mail has been sent", so that they don't get redirected to the PHP site.

Unfortunately, it's not working for me. If I click on "Send", it shows me the script.
So I'm not sure if the AJAX code is correct. Could anyone help me?

```
$(document).ready(function()    {
        $("#kontakt").submit(function() {
                if($("von").val() == "" || $("mail").val() == "" || $("nachricht").val() ==""){
                    $("#response").html("bitte fülle alle felder aus!");
                    } else  {
                        $("#response").("Lade...");
                        $.ajax({
                            type:"POST",
                            url:"senden.php",
                            data:"von=" + $("von").val() + "&mail=" + $("mail").val() + ="&nachricht=" + $("nachricht").val(),
                            success: function (msg)
                            {
                            $("#response").html(msg);
                            }
                        );
                    });
                }
            return false;
            });

        });

<form method="post" action="senden.php" id="kontakt">
            <h3 class="title">Nur nicht sch&uuml;chtern !</h3>
            <input type="text" name="von" placeholder="Name" id="von">
            <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="E-mail" id="mail">
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Nachricht" id="nachricht"></textarea>
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="senden"></submit>
            </form>
            <div id="response"></div>
```

I put it also on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PqKFb/

Comment: you are using type post and sending data in url.so when you will receive in php through $_POST . it will not be found. and plz put you php code to handle ajax

Comment: Have you tried to add "done" function and "fail" function to debug?

Comment: $("#response").("Lade..."); ??

Comment: 'code'<?php
 $empf = "kontakt@awesom-media.de";
 $betreff = $_POST ['betreff'];
 $from = "From: ";
 $from .=$_POST['von'];
 $from .= <";"
 $from .= $_POST['mail'];
 $from.= "\n";
 $from .="Content-Type: text/html\n";
 $text = $_POST['nachricht'];
 
 mail($empf, $betreff, $text, $from);
 echo "Vielen Dank, Nachricht wurde weitergeleietet.";
 
?>' thats my php   the repsonse box is the divbox where the message should be shown. [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJg6CAswAjo) im trying to make the same think like in this video but even if i doit the same way is it not working

Comment: Add the code to your question, not here

Comment: You could use data: $('#kontakt').serialize()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/K8wVb/2/)**

Since you are using ajax , do it without refreshing the page

Here is the edited code

### HTML

```
<form method="post" id="kontakt">
     <h3 class="title">Nur nicht sch&uuml;chtern !</h3>

    <input type="text" name="von" placeholder="Name" id="von">
    <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="E-mail" id="mail">
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Nachricht" id="nachricht"></textarea>
    <input id="submit" type="button" value="senden">
    </submit>
</form>
<div id="response"></div>
```

corrected the mistakes in your code, and it would be better to use `$('#kontakt').serialize()`,it will take the data automatically

### code

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        if ($("#von").val() == "" || $("#mail").val() == "" || $("#nachricht").val() == "") {
            $("#response").html("bitte fülle alle felder aus!");
        } else {
            $("#response").html("Lade...");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: $('#kontakt').serialize(),
                url: "senden.php",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                    $("#response").html(msg);
                }

            });
        }

    });

});
```

### senden.php

```
<?php

$data=$_POST['serialize'];
$von=$data['von'];  //access data like this

?>
```

Hope this helps,Thank you

Comment: I suggest you to do a trick that it always work to me, using "fail" and "always" ajax functions to check for errors and realize when post is done. I send the result to a div that I hide later making it easy to debug deeper during development.

Comment: @MaximilianoRios the problem was mainly because of several syntax error in his code , then how do you think fail and always works. And thanks for your suggestion I will use it in future

Comment: i used your method. firstavil thank you sarath.

So far is it working. But i have some problem with the php. '<?php

$data=$_POST['serialize'];
$von=$data['von'];
$mail=$data['mail'];  
$nachricht=$data['nachricht'];    

?>' thats my script . is it correct so far ? im not so into php . and how do i get the emails.

Comment: @Peyman ,yes it is,you can check it and revert back,for email  $email=$data['message'] where 'message' is the name of your textarea

Comment: $email=$data['kontakt@.....'] i put this to the rest of php and i uploadet to my webspace

Comment: for email $email=$data['message'] where 'message' is the name of your textarea

Comment: oh ok. i changed it but if u cklick on send there is just Lade, which means loading.

Comment: Thats my php script right now <?php

$data=$_POST['serialize'];
$von=$data['von'];
$mail=$data['mail'];  
$nachricht=$data['nachricht'];   
$email=$data[message]; 

?>  could u take a look at www.awesom-media.de

what im not understandig ist how do i get the mails , i mean i must put somewhere my email to receive it or not ?

Comment: Do you want to store it somewhere

Comment: no no, i just whant that if someone filling this out that i get the message at it@awesom-media.de. and i uploadet to my website. and its working but i dont get the message.

And what else strang ist ( for me ) . if i click on send then come a lil window where is written ( by chrome ) the site www...... is saying : and then is here nothing " 

if u could take a look at the site u know what i mean .

thank u for ur help to here sarath

Comment: There is nothing in the alert box because you are not echoing anything from server ie php, the code works perfectly,please mark the answer as correct

Comment: but why im not getting the messages ? what do i have to type. and how do i make it with the echo

Comment: may be you should send me the server side file ie .php at  cleardoubts123@gmail.com. I will verify and revert by tommorow,Is that ok with you?

Comment: sned it to u the php file

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a few errors in your javascript, I have fixed these and it seems to be working.

http://jsfiddle.net/PqKFb/8/

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#kontakt").submit(function () {
            if ($("von").val() == "" || $("mail").val() == "" || $("nachricht").val() == "") {
                $("#response").html("bitte fülle alle felder aus!");
            } else {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "senden.php",
                    data: "von=" + $("von").val() + "&mail=" + $("mail").val() + "&nachricht=" + $("nachricht").val(),
                    success: function (msg) {
                        $("#response").html(msg);
                    }
                });
            }

            return false;
        });

    });
```

With the return false in the submit event it should not actually submit the form anyway even though you have specified the action page.